# ¿Como puedo pasar toda la request a un json?

Tags: java, html, formularios, requests

estoy haciendo una aplicacion de gestión de ligas, dentro de esta tengo una pagina para añadir los resultados de los partidos, en la que cargo 2 arraylist de jugadores (equipo local, y equipo visitante) y unos checks, para marcar que jugadores juegan, al activar el check se habilita un input para poner cuantos goles ha marcado cada jugador.

Mi duda es que quiero guardar directamente todos los datos de la request en un json. En el request iria el numero de goles de cada equipo, y los check e inputs activados.

No se si me podreis ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: buenas. Que has intentado hasta ahora? date cuenta que no tenemos idea de como es tu bbdd, donde lo querrias guardar, como recojes los valores del formulario (entiendo que usas formulario, aunque podria ser una Api Rest...). Puedes darnos mas informacion al respecto?

Comment: de moetno he intentado esto, pero no me funciona
`JsonObject jsonJugadores = new JsonObject();
    List<FileItem> items = null;
    try {
     items = (List<FileItem>) new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseParameterMap(request);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (FileItem item : items) {
     if (item.isFormField()) {
      jsonJugadores.addProperty(item.getFieldName(), item.getString("UTF-8"));
     }
    }`

Si, recojo los datos a trves de un formulario, y lo envio a un servlet